# how to get password from string "password is Rtt3Ved36" by regexp?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

on condition that string may be is "password Rtt3Ved36" (without "is").

```
(?<=password\ is|password\ ).*
```

That regexp doesn't work, because always return "is Rtt3Ved36" (but i need "Rtt3Ved36"). How to keep order in OR condition?

Comment: What if the password starts with "is"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
password(?: is)?\s*(.*)
```

and grab Group 1 value.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=password%28%3F%3A%20is%29%3F%5Cs*%28.*%29&i=password%20Rtt3Ved36%0D%0Apassword%20is%20Rtt3Ved36).

**Details**

- `password` - a literal substring
- `(?: is)?` - an optional substring space + `is`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than a newline.

In C#:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"password(?: is)?\s*(.*)");
var result = string.Empty;
if (m.Success) 
{
    result = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Should the `\s*` be changed to `\s+`? My quick test with input texts of `password issue` `password is issue` gave results of `sue` and `issue` respectively but I expected them to give the same result.

Comment: @AdrianHHH That is fine tuning. You may also use a word boundary, [`@"password(?: is)?\b\s*(.*)"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=password%28%3f%3a+is%29%3f%5cb%5cs*%28.*%29&i=password+Rtt3Ved36%0d%0apassword+is+Rtt3Ved36%0d%0apassword+issue%0d%0apassword+is+issue)

Answer (score -3):

According to this site: https://regex101.com/ your regex does work and returns "Rtt3Ved36".

Comment: This is more suited as a comment.